# Stricter Interface Design vs Extension Method Overloads

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I'm writing a library that exposes metrics as observables, in which I have the following interface for a Gauge (represents a value that can change over time). This is generic to allow consumers to record values of any type, e.g. `double`, `int` or some custom unit type like a `ByteCount`.

```cs
public interface IGauge<TValue> : IObservable<TValue>
{
}
```

Consumers may be interested in knowing how much this value is changing between observed values, so I want them to be able to easily turn the series of observable values into observable "deltas" representing the difference between the current sample and the previous one. This is useful for e.g. calculating the rate of change of a particular value. In the generic case, this could be done as follows:

```cs
public class Delta<TValue>
{
    public TValue PreviousValue { get; }
    public TValue CurrentValue { get; }
}

public interface IGauge<TValue> : IObservable<TValue>
{
    IObservable<Delta<TValue>> Delta { get; }
}

public class Gauge<TValue> : IGauge<TValue>
{
    // ...
}

// Consumer
var gauge = new Gauge<TValue>();
gauge.Delta.Subscribe(delta => Console.WriteLine(
    $"Value changed from {delta.PreviousValue} to {delta.CurrentValue}"));
```

What I'm struggling with is how to best override this behaviour for gauges using types that can be subtracted. Ideally for a `IGauge<double>` the `Delta` property defined above would return the actual difference `currentValue - previousValue` as an `IObservable<double>` rather than an `IObservable<Delta<double>>`.

Since I'm effectively trying to model the `IGauge<double>` as a special case of an `IGauge<TValue>` where the value is subtractable and hence can be used as the delta, one approach would be to update my interface design by making the type of the delta generic, i.e.

```cs
public interface IGauge<TValue, TDelta> : IObservable<TValue>
{
    IObservable<TDelta> Delta { get; }
}

public interface IGauge<TValue> : IGauge<TValue, Delta<TValue>>
{
}

// Not the best name, I know!
public interface ISubtractableGauge<TValue> : IGauge<TValue, TValue>
{
}

public class DoubleGauge : ISubtractableGauge<double>
{
    // ...
}

// Consumer
var gauge = new DoubleGauge();
gauge.Delta.Subscribe(delta => Console.WriteLine($"Value changed by {delta}"));
```

Another approach is to move this functionality out into an extension method for `IGauge<TValue>` and then create an overload for the more specific `IGauge<double>` to override this default behaviour, i.e.

```cs
public interface IGauge<TValue> : IObservable<TValue>
{
}

public static IObservable<Delta<TValue>> Delta<TValue>(this IGauge<TValue> gauge)
{
    // ...
}

public static IObservable<double> Delta(this IGauge<double> gauge)
{
    // ...
}

public class Gauge<TValue> : IGauge<TValue>
{
    // ...
}

// Consumer
var gauge = new Gauge<double>();
gauge.Delta().Subscribe(delta => Console.WriteLine($"Value changed by {delta}"));
```

Both approaches work as intended, but I'm having a hard time choosing between them. The extension method approach provides a slightly more elegant solution as it leads to a simpler type model, but it feels wrong that I'm using them to effectively implement part of the `IGauge<TValue>` interface in such a way that the contract for the `Delta` method can implicitly vary depending on `TValue`.

Are there any other approaches that achieve the same result, and what are the main considerations for choosing one approach over the other?

Comment: Do the observers need absolute values in the original units of measure? What about providing a relative measure, e.g. percentages? Then you could fix the data type to e.g. `decimal`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny A relative delta certainly might be useful, but I'd consider this an additional feature rather than an alternative to the absolute delta.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing a subtraction delegate to the constructor of gauges. So that this subtraction problem does not pollute the interface. Like this, the gauge can handle the deltas itself.

I propose the following interface. Whether you want to expose the previous value is up to you. I made the `Delta` property nullable, since the first value has no delta. This requires the `struct` constraint, forcing `TValue` to be a value type.

```
public interface IGauge<TValue> : IObservable<TValue>
    where TValue : struct
{
    TValue Value { get; }
    TValue? Delta { get; }
}
```

A possible implementation:

```
public class Gauge<TValue> : IGauge<TValue>
    where TValue : struct
{
    private TValue? _previousValue;
    private readonly Func<TValue, TValue, TValue> _subtract;

    public Gauge(Func<TValue, TValue, TValue> subtract)
    {
        _subtract = subtract;
    }

    private TValue _value;
    public TValue Value
    {
        get => _value;
        private set {
            _previousValue = _value;
            if (!value.Equals(_value)) {
                _value = value;
                //TODO: Notify observer.
            }
        }
    }

    public TValue? Delta => _previousValue.HasValue
        ? (TValue?)_subtract(_value, _previousValue.Value)
        : null;

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TValue> observer)
    {
        //TODO: Add implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

I assume that the gauge has some internal mechanism, e.g. a timer, to sample and change the values. It would do so by assigning new values to the private setter of the `Value` property. Otherwise, add a (public) setter to the `Value` property in the interface.

You can then create a specialized gauge type like this:

```
public class DoubleGauge : Gauge<double>
{
    public DoubleGauge() : base((x, y) => x - y)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Another consideration is: different observers could poll the gauge at different intervals. Then they would observe different deltas between the polls, and it would be the observers' task to calculate the deltas.

Comment: +1 for both solutions, either use a callback function or let consumers handle the specificness of calculating delta. Either way, this class shouldn't care how to calculate a delta. I would use a different name though than _subtract_ because that sounds too specific. Perhaps _reduceCallback_, _aggregator_ or just _selector_.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a nice solution for when `TDelta` is always equal to `TValue`, but I only want this to be the case where e.g. `TValue` is `double`. For non-subtractable types I want `TDelta` to be `Delta<TValue>`.